# Understanding Memory Management retain count

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have an instant variable "obj1" in MyClass.h.

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *arrObj1;
```

and in MyClass.m **viewDidLoad** method, i have allocated another object "obj2" and assign that to obj1.

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSMutableArray *arrObj2 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"a",@"b",@"c", nil];
    NSLog(@"arrObj2 count %lu",(unsigned long)[arrObj2 retainCount]);
    self.arrObj1 = arrObj2;

    NSLog(@"arrObj1 count %lu",(unsigned long)[self.arrObj1 retainCount]);
    NSLog(@"arrObj2 count %lu",(unsigned long)[arrObj2 retainCount]);
}
```

Here is the output

```
2015-08-19 11:06:14.461 MyClass[1812:24133] arrObj2 count 1
2015-08-19 11:06:16.332 MyClass[1812:24133] arrObj1 count 2
2015-08-19 11:06:17.327 MyClass[1812:24133] arrObj2 count 2
```

I am not getting how arrObj2 get retain Count value 2.
please explain me.

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A more relevant question to your problem is: Why do `arrObj` and `arrObj2` seem to share properties? And the answer is they're two references to the **same object**. That means the same array is referenced strongly in the same place; that is, `arrObj1` and `arrObj2` are actually the same array. That's why you see a `retainCount` of 2, though you shouldn't use `retainCount` for this. (More on that later.) Compare the addresses of the arrays in the debugger instead; they will be the same. If you add an object to one array, it'll be added to "the other."

You can fix that by using copy on the property declaration instead, or by changing `self.arrObj1 = arrObj2` to `self.arrObj1 = [arrObj2 mutableCopy]` . (Edit: I'm not actually sure changing the property type to copy will help here, since it's a mutable type. It would work if it was just an `NSArray`, though.)

I hope that answers your question, but now I want to explain why it's the wrong question. Please don't take any offence, because learning this is important and not easy. :)

### Think in terms of relationship type, not retain/release

You shouldn't be thinking in terms of retain counts at all, but in terms of `strong` and `weak` relationship: A `strong` relationship expresses an ownership interest in the object, a `weak` relationship doesn't and will be converted to `nil` shortly after all ownership interests in the object are removed. Also, note that the `retain` property type is deprecated: it should be `strong` in ARC code.

### Don't use `retainCount`.

Don't use retainCount. Or, if you prefer, [When to use Retain Count](http://whentouseretaincount.com):

> Never.

Then there's Apple's [official documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSObject/retainCount), which begins:

> This method is of no value in debugging memory management issues.

Or there's [this from bbum](http://www.friday.com/bbum/2011/12/18/retaincount-is-useless/), which I consider even better. He goes into great detail about why retainCount is useless, concluding with:

> Bottom line: the only time the absolute retainCount can be conclusively used for analytic purposes is if you have the backtrace of every retain and release that contributed to the current retain count’s value (there is another use case, documented at the end). If you have that, then you don’t need the retain count and, fortunately, Instruments is already generally quite adept at producing a per-object inventory of retains and releases for you.

Basically, it's value is not useful. It will return (in some cases) the number of times an object has been retained without releasing. It does not (and can not) take the number of times it has been autoreleased into account. And it will not always return the "correct" value even without considering autorelease, since some objects can never be deallocated from RAM.

Answer (score 0):

in Objective-C an object is a reference type.

The retain count is increased the first time when the object was allocated.
When the object is assigned to `arrObj1` the object is not copied when the property is declared as `retain` or `strong` so `arrObj1` and `arrObj2` contain the pointer to the same object. The implicit setter of the property `arrObj1` increases the retain counter a second time.

Answer (score 0):

Memory management is the programming discipline of managing the life cycles of objects and freeing them when they are no longer needed.

Managing object memory is a matter of performance; if an application doesn’t free unneeded objects, its memory footprint grows and performance suffers.

Memory management in a Cocoa application that doesn’t use garbage collection is based on a reference counting model. When you create or copy an object, its retain count is 1.

Thereafter other objects may express an ownership interest in your object, which increments its retain count.

The owners of an object may also relinquish their ownership interest in it, which decrements the retain count. When the retain count becomes zero, the object is deallocated (destroyed).

Check this image.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Art/memory_management.jpg

Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

After the statement

```
self.arrObj1 = arrObj2;
```

the variable `arrObj2` and the property `self.arrObj1` point to **the very same object.**

If they point to the same object, and `arrObj2` has a reference count of 2, what reference count do you expect `self.arrObj1` to have?

Answer (score 0):

Reason why retain count is coming as 2 is because you have used retain for NSMutableArray *arrObj1, so in effect 
when you allocate arrObj2 retain count become 1,
the when you assign it to arrObj1 as its having a retain property, count increase - becoming 2.
arrObj2 is same  arrObj1 as you have not copied it (as Steven Fisher in  above answer pointed out) both has same retain count.

If you make arrObj1 to assign property then count will be remained as 1.

Answer (score 0):

Simply put, the object pointed to by `arrObj2` *is the same object* pointed to by `arrObj1`. Instruments shows us that this object gets +1 retain count when you called `initWithObjects`:

[image]

And that it got +2 retain count when you called `setArrObj1` (i.e. you used the `self.arrObj1 = ...` syntax):

[image]

For demonstrations using Instruments' "Allocations" tool for tracking memory usage, see WWDC 2013 video [Fixing Memory Issues](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2013/?id=410) and WWDC 2012 video [iOS App Performance: Memory](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/?id=242). Bottom line, while it will take some practice to efficiently find the correct objects in the "Allocations" tool, this "Record reference counts" feature is invaluable in finding where the strong references to the objects in question were established.

I'm sure you've seen it, but I'd also refer you to the [Advanced Memory Management Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/MemoryMgmt.html).

Answer (score -1):

When you alloc a new memory area (I call it M) and assign it to obj2, the retainCount of M is 1.

When you do: self.obj1 = obj2.
Because self.obj1 is a retain property, so M will be retain +1, so its retainCount = 2 now.

Cause obj1 & obj2 are references to M, so their retainCount are 2.

Let try [obj1 release] and get retainCount of obj2 again to check.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Try `NSLog(@"%d", [[[NSNumber alloc] initWithFloat:42.0] retainCount]);` on an x86_64 Yosemite or El Capitan machine...